# opencv how to track objects after optical flow?

Tags: opencv

After doing optical flow (lk) on a video what's the best way to find the objects based on this data and track them?

This probably sounds very noobish, but I would like to be able to define a clear outline around objects, so if it's a weirdly shaped bottle or something to be able to detect the edges.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure LK is the best algorithm, since it computes the motion of a sparse set of corner-like points, and tracking behaves usually better from a dense optical flow result (such as Farneback or Horn Schunck). After computing the flow, as a first step, you can do some thresholding on its norm (to retain the moving parts), and try to extract connected regions from this result. But be warned that your tasks is not going to be easy if you don't have a model of the object you want to track.

On the other hand, if you are primarily interested in tracking and a bit of interactivity is acceptable, you can have a look at the camshift sample code to see how to select and track an image region based on its appearance.

**--- EDIT ---**

If your camera is static, then use background subtraction instead. Using OpenCV 2.4 beta, you have to look for the class BackgroundSubtractor and its subclasses in the video module documentation.

Note also that optical flow can be realtime (or not very far) with good choices of parameters, and also with GPU implementation. On windows, you can use flowlib from [TU Graz/Gpu4Vision group](http://gpu4vision.icg.tugraz.at). OpenCV also has some GPU dense optical flow, for example the class gpu::BroxOpticalFlow.

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

Joining single-pixel detections into big objects is a task called [connected component labelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling). There is a fast algorithm for that, implemented in OpenCV. So this gives you a pipeline which is:

- motion detection (pix level) ---> connected comp. labeling ---> object tracking (adding motion information, possible trajectories for Kalman filtering...).

But we'll have to stop here, because we'll soon be far beyond the scope of your initial question ;-)

Comment: Got it. Give me a couple of days to implement it, it sounds good.

Comment: Quick followup question: Is there a faster algorithm than optical-flow to just detect where movement is in a video so that the user doesn't have to manually select the part he is interested in for camshift? (I was wondering why you said camshaft and then safari auto-corrected my spelling too)

Comment: Your answer has been more than awesome. Thank you so much! But I am stuck at how to detect the objects from the result from background subtraction. Is there something I could use that would connect them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TLD or CLM for doing object tracking (it is loosely based on the the idea of optical flow tracking and model learning at the same time). 
You can find following links useful
https://www.gnebehay.com/tld/
https://www.gnebehay.com/cmt/